# requests with Python 3.x : missing location with 302 status_code

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I am using requests in Python 3 as follows:

```
r = requests.get(d, allow_redirects=False)
```

(where `d` is the url, namely `d = 'http://1490korn.com'`).

What I get is:

```
print(r.status_code)
302
```

And:

```
print(r.headers)
{'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'Location': 
'/VaZfZ/', 'Connection': 'Close', 'Proxy-Connection': 'Close'}
```

Why do I get so little information (for my other urls, I get additional info like the date). And, in particular: why is the location information so strange?

Comment: That's not a Python 3 or requests problem. That's a server error.

Comment: Put differently: nothing you do on the client side will alter this. The server is broken.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why the downvote? How could I have improved the question?

Comment: And, if the server is broken: why is there no error according to the status code?

Comment: The server doesn't *know* it is broken.

Comment: Software is not perfect. If a HTTP server is *mostly* working it can figure out something internal is wrong and give you a 500 error. Here, there appears to be a load balancer in front that is serving invalid responses half of the time. Not everything on the web is working as it should.

Comment: And in the meantime, the flakiness seems to have dissipated. I think we flushed out the bad responses from the load balancer or cache or whatever was serving these bad responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is just broken, half of the time. Nothing you can do on the client side will remedy that. It's not a Python problem, not a `requests` problem.

When you use basic network tools like `curl`, some of the time you'll  see the exact same issues:

```
$ curl -D - http://1490korn.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 13:08:44 GMT
```

The `-D -` command line switch tells `curl` to write out the headers it receives.

This time the `Date` header was present, and the `Location` path is still wrong but wrong in a different way. It appears the server is experiencing some reliability issues, because when you repeat the command several times, some of the responses are complete:

```
$ curl -D - http://1490korn.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 13:10:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: http://www.kornradio.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

This is a valid response; note the many differences in headers.